# C# FTP Upload and Download

Tags: c#, upload, ftp, download

Is there any refernece to C# that I'm able to upload some files from my computer (where program is running) to my FTP that is somwere else and again to download that files to my other computer (on that other computer I'm running program again.)

Comment: You could have found the answer by using Google within 1 minute. Further more this question does not fit into stackoverflow. Please read the faq

Answer (score 13):

Use `FtpWebRequest` and `FtpWebResponse` classes. for more information see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718.aspx

**Code**

Upload (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms229715.aspx):

```
namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Download (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229711.aspx):

```
namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();  
        }
    }
}
```